# Can I change the opacity of the navbar in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, opacity

I stumbled onto this [site](https://testflightapp.com/): and started thinking.  Is this possible using twitter's [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)? I don't see an opacity setting in the css file?  Is it as easy as adding it.

Answer (score 18):

In general, this is possible. Testflightapp uses the `background-color: rgba` attribute with an opacity level.

So if you want to set a background color with opacity to on of you element use this CSS:

```
elementname {
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5); /* Red [0-255], Green [0-255], Blue [0-255], Alpha [0-1] */
}
```

If you want to set the opacity on the element as a whole use:

```
elementname {
    opacity: 0.5; /* opacity [0-1] */
    -moz-opacity: 0.5; /* opacity [0-1] */
    -webkit-opacity: 0.5; /* opacity [0-1] */
}
```

This is only supported by browsers that support CSS3.

Comment: And if the users browser doesn't supprot CSS3 is the opacity simply ignored?

Comment: Yes, a browser that does not understand a property, ignores that property

Answer (score 8):

A late answer, but I just found this question whilst looking up something very similar.

If you're using bootstrap with less, so that you're building the css yourself as part of an asset pipeline you should set opacity using the utility macro.

```
selector {
    .opacity(50);   /* opacity [0->100]  */
}
```

It'll define the correct browser prefixes, including the IE filter syntax for you.

Comment: Just for googlers: the `.opacity()` macro expects a value between 0 and 1 (http://lesselements.com/)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bootstrap with sass. You can use the opacity mixin.

```
@include opacity([from 0-100]);
```

This will take handle all browser compatibilities (if supported) dealing with opacity.